# Hide Google Chrome back/forward/refresh buttons

Tags: google-chrome

There are keyboard shortcuts for the back/forward/refresh buttons, so I hardly use those three buttons.

Can I hide them to give space to the address bar?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they can't be removed.

Comment: When Chrome 13 came out, they had a compact navigation option; but looks like it was removed, due to some bugs they couldn't fix.  At the moment, I cannot find anything else that would allow it to be removed.  FF can, however, but doesn't look like chrome, at the moment can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Unlike other browsers, Google Chrome is inflexible for this kind of UI change. Only thing you can remove is home icon from options